# Device Farms that allow React-Native with Detox and Jest

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, mobile-automation

I hope someone can help with this as I'm honestly stuck.

We have an application written in react-native and we are on the hunt for a device farm that is compatible with the tests we have written (detox-Jest). If anyone knows of a device farm that would meet this criteria would be great.

So far I've spoken to Browser Stack but that was unsuccessful they have React - Native on their road map but no definite dates of when it will go live . So I'm reaching out to AWS (once I get clearance) but just wondering what else is out there?

I tried to do this a couple of years ago (it was unsuccessful) but that was 2018. I'm hoping in the 2021 things have changed somewhat.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saucelabs is another big device testing service. Have you tried them?

Comment: I tried them a few years ago but they may be a possibility.  I've used them before so I know they are good but a little slow...but solid

Answer (score 1):

I use Java + Appium for real device testing in BitBar cloud.
In your case, it looks like they also support Detox, please refer to this link:

https://bitbar.com/blog/automate-detox-mobile-tests-on-real-devices-in-the-cloud/

There is a free trial and IMO their support is very good.

Comment: thanks  man,  I will reach out to them and see if they work react native.

Answer (score 1):

I did set up with Genymotion emulators for Android. Works perfectly even in 2 parallel threads:

- [Genymotion project](https://cloud.geny.io/)
- [Setup example](https://medium.com/genymobile/scale-your-e2e-react-native-ui-testing-with-detox-on-genymotion-cloud-android-virtual-devices-b3effbc7eccc)
- [Github actions runner](https://github.com/Genymobile/genymotion-saas-github-action)
- [Detox setup example](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/examples/demo-react-native-jest/detox.config.js)

Comment: Welcome to the community. You should read https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer specifically about providing context for links.  Links go stale over time. Can you summarize what each of these are?